# Connecting to a ClearDB database in a Heroku application using PHP fails with no error message

Tags: php, mysql, heroku

I've ruled out the possibility of supplying an incorrect name or password in mysqli_connect, because when I change them to make them incorrect on purpose, I actually get an error message from mysqli_connect_error(). With the code below, the connection fails, but I get no error message. I am out of ideas. What do you recommend I do next to debug?

```
 <?php

        $con = mysqli_connect("eu-cdbr-west-02.cleardb.net", "b497f08cc1919a", "7d15759b", "heroku_8d537c3a6f00758"); 

        if (!$conn) 
        {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        echo "Connected successfully";


    ?>
```

Edit: As Seth pointed out, I mistyped the name of a variable. I'm sorry, I'll see myself out. :(

Comment: We all make mistakes like that. Just mark Seth's answer as the answer.

Comment: Error reporting would have been of help here.

Comment: Btw, I hope those aren't real login credentials. They look to be and if so, you'd better go change those now.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that showing the password here means that it's compromised. I'm just setting up a sandbox to learn, it's ok. I'll change it when I deploy for real.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `$con` for the connection but checking `$conn`. If you don't see the "Connected successfully" text your app as a whole likely has yet another problem. Usually you'd put that in the `else` part.